# How does Java handle multiple client keys in the keystore but 1 in trust store when doing mtls

Tags: ssh, java, mtls

I have a situation where I am trying to setup mtls where the client has multiple keys. I cant seem to find how the resolution of which alias works so can somewhere here guide me?

How does Java decide which alias to use when their are multiple keys in the keystore but only 1 of them is in the server trust store?

**Update**

Currently I have the following code

```
public class ConfigurableAliasKeyManagerFactory extends KeyManagerFactory {
  ...
  private static final class ConfigurableAliasKeyManagerFactorySpi extends KeyManagerFactorySpi {
    ...
    @Override
    protected KeyManager[] engineGetKeyManagers() {
       return Arrays.stream(this.delegate.getKeyManagers())
         .filter(X509ExtendedKeyManager.class::isInstance)
         .map(X509ExtendedKeyManager.class::cast)
         .map(this::wrap)
         .toArray(KeyManager[]::new);
    }
  }
  ...
  protected static final class ConfigurableAliasKeyManager extends X509ExtendedKeyManager {
    @Getter
    private final String alias;

    public ConfigurableAliasKeyManager(X509ExtendedKeyManager keyManager, String alias) {
        this.delegate = keyManager;
        this.alias = alias;
    }
    @Override
    public String chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
        return (this.alias != null) ? this.alias : this.delegate.chooseClientAlias(keyType, issuers, socket);
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

But the break point doesn't seem to work in `chooseClientAlias` so I don't think it is getting called

Comment: _IF_ server uses its truststore to specify desired CAs in the CertRequest handshake message -- which _most_ do including Java JSSE server using default TrustManager -- then Java JSSE client using default KeyManager uses that info (along with other criteria like acceptable signature algorithms) to select which cert-and-key (i.e. privateKeyEntry) to use. You can see this if you look at the handshake, e.g. with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake`. If you override the TrustManager and/or KeyManager it depends on your code which you didn't show.

Comment: Is there a case where multiple keys are available, (IE Server trust store has 2 of the client's certs) and when this happens how do I distinguish and which one to use in that case or does it even matter?

Comment: Also what is the chooseEngineClientAlias doing then? When does that get called?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 added some code to show you what I am trying

Comment: If the KeyManager you show is in fact used, yes `chooseClientAlias` should be called when client `SSLSocket` connects to a server that sends CertRequest, and its return value then used in calls to `getPrivateKey` and `getCertificateChain`. `chooseEngineClientAlias` should be called by client `SSLEngine` in the same situation. If this is not happening as you expect, you should probably ask on StackOverflow with a _reproducible_ example. If server accepts multiple CAs and client has certs using more than one, it should be okay to use any of them.

Comment: I have a reproduceable simple example I will post it shortly, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things but I think the easiest is just post the example

https://github.com/jrgleason/spring-boot-mtls

This seems to work correctly. To test the fail case change the client alias to something like client3